# geometry nodes with node groups - recursivity on instances

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have this implementation of a node group in geometry nodes, able to place different circles inside another circle (the outer one being of radius R1, the most inner one of radius R4 and the small ones of radius R2, aligned on a circle of radius R3.
[image: Node group implementation]

[image: First level]

When I connect these node groups, I can recursively apply the pattern to the central circle (see picture) [image: 3 levels of recursivity on the central circle] and [image: here]

My question is : How can I also apply this recursivity to the small circles ?

Edit : I added the position of the different radii on the image

The blend file
[image]

Comment: You may want to take a look how I do it here with Sierpiński Triangle: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/286554/60486

Comment: repeat zone. (in 4.0 I thinking)